# Typescript: Access property value from type/interface declaration

Tags: typescript

I have a following type

```
export type OfferTypes = {
__typename: 'OfferTypeTypePagination';

items: any[];

total: number;
};
```

is there a way to access `OfferTypeTypePagination` as a string from the code (eg `console.log(OfferTypes.__typename)`) ?

Answer (score 0):

When you export a type, the 'OfferTypeTypePagination' is not a value or default value that for __typename, it is basically another type.

That means every variable which is OfferTypes will have a property named "__typename" and only have one value, that is always 'OfferTypeTypePagination'

So your code should be like this:

```
const key = {
    'OfferTypeTypePagination': null,
};

export type OfferTypes = {
    __typename: keyof typeof key;

    items: any[];

    total: number;
};

console.log(Object.keys(key)[0]);
```

Comment: unfortunately this is a generated code, i can not modify it

Comment: in this case, I can only say there's no way to get it because type and value are different, you can't log it in a console or use it.